# Pandas read_csv is super slow on NFS

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nfs

I have very simple script that uses `pandas.parse_csv` method to load large dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

USE_COLUMNS = [0,1,2,11,13,14]

def parse_csv(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,
                     header=None,
                     compression='bz2',
                     delim_whitespace=True,
                     dtype={11:np.float32, 13:np.float32, 14:np.float32},
                     skip_blank_lines=True,
                     skiprows=4,
                     parse_dates=[[1,2]],
                     usecols=USE_COLUMNS,
                     error_bad_lines=False,
                     infer_datetime_format=True,
                     iterator=True,
                     chunksize=100000,
                     low_memory=False,
                     engine='c')
    return df

fname = 'test.log.bz2'
iter = parse_csv(fname)
df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk[14] > 60000] for chunk in iter])
print df
```

File `test.log.bz2` is 1.1GB compressed and 5+GB uncompressed, it has 15 columns only some of them is used. On my local machine this scripts needs about 200 seconds to run. But on production machine it runs 53 minutes (x16 slowdown)! How can I fix this?

On my local machine I'm using SATA SSD and on production machine NFS backed filesystem is the only option.

I'm using pandas version 0.16.2.

I run this script on my local machine under strace, this is results:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 57.09    0.038753           2     15618           mremap
 18.83    0.012780           0    109476           munmap
 14.81    0.010055           0    109669           mmap
  3.44    0.002337           0    259922           read
  2.10    0.001427           0      5549      4780 open
  1.45    0.000987           1       713           brk
```

`strace` results in production environment:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 92.41    0.491816          46     10766           mremap
  4.59    0.024412           7      3491      2814 open
  0.76    0.004065           0      9897           read
  0.75    0.003999          15       274       274 unlink
  0.50    0.002652           3       974       838 stat
  0.47    0.002498        1249         2           clone
  0.35    0.001865           0      4659           munmap
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.532200                 37118      3997 total
```

Comment: well, put your production NFS onto SSDs, use 10GiB ethernet and then your can compare the speed ;) Now seriously - I would start thinking about HDFS and Apache Spark for 5+GB files

Comment: I can unpack this archive file in 10 seconds on production machine.

Comment: how long does it take to copy packed file onto machine where pandas is running and to unpack it there? I mean just these two operations, without reading/parsing CSV...

Comment: Just several seconds.

Comment: And how long does it take to parse (read_csv) unpacked file on the prod. machine after it was copied and unpacked?

Comment: I think low_memory is deprecated. About reading time, column 0 is set to be read but the type is not provided in dtype. What is the type of the column? Also, now that I think about it, I'm not sure about the interaction between dtype and parse_dates.

Comment: did you try to read your file completely (not in chunks)? anyway you're concatenating it into single DF afterwards, so you could save on `concat()`

Comment: @vmg I'm using old version of pandas and without `low_memory` I'm getting warnings from time to time. Column `0` is a string, without explicit `dtype` everything works the same way. The only difference is that last three columns became np.float64.

Comment: @MaxU I'm reading file in chunks because I have pretty large archives in production environment (about 10Gb compressed). There is no way I can load it into memory. I'm reading file by chunks to filter it. Resulting dataframe has only several hundred rows.

Comment: @MaxU I'll try to parse unpacked file on prod. It will take some time, I'm running this script under strace on production server now.

Comment: have you tried increasing NFS read-write chunk size? -o rsize=8192,wsize=8192

Comment: It's at least 20 to 1 in terms of the time it takes pandas vs the time it takes `fread` (in R) on the same system with the same file in my experience. We need something better than `read.csv`. A lot better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to pre-filter your data (using standard tools: `bzip2` and `gawk`) before loading it to pandas:

```
bzip2 -dc /path/to/test.log.bz2 | gawk -F"," 'NR > 4 && $15 > 600000.0 {print}' > /path/to/test_filtered.log
```

this should be much faster and will consume much less memory

please pay attention at `$15` instead of `chunk[14]` - AWK counts columns starting from 1

after that you can simply load prefiltered uncompressed CSV into pandas

PS you may also want to [tune up](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/performance.html) your NFS